# FaultRule in SpikeArrest not working?

Tags: apigee

I'm trying to return a custom error message when a proxy goes above its rate in a SpikeArrest policy, but SpikeArrest doesn't seem to trigger the policy assigned to handle the fault:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<SpikeArrest async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true"     name="SpikeArrest.BurstProtection">
    <DisplayName>SpikeArrest.BurstProtection</DisplayName>
    <FaultRules>
        <FaultRule>
            <Policy>
                <Name>RaiseFault.BurstProtection</Name>
            </Policy>
        </FaultRule>
    </FaultRules>
    <Properties/>
    <Identifier ref="request.header.sender-id"/>
    <MessageWeight ref="1"/>
    <Rate>1pm</Rate>
</SpikeArrest>
```

I've used the  construct elsewhere before (mostly in VerifyAPIKey) and it's always worked fine, but not in this one.

Am I missing something?

We're running Apigee Edge (installation package was 14.01.0.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<FaultRules>` functionality was deprecated within Policies some time ago.

If you want to raise a custom fault for SpikeArrest, first, ensure `continueOnError="true"` attribute is set in your SpikeArrest Policy.  That allows you to ignore the system's generic response output.  Second, you can check for the following condition in a subsequent policy, leveraging `ratelimit.<spike_arrest_policy_name>.exceed.count` variable:

```
...
            <!-- Spike Arrest policy -->
            <Step>
                <Name>SpikeArrest.BurstProtection</Name>
            </Step>
            <!-- RaiseFault for Spike Arrest violation -->
            <Step>
                <Condition>(ratelimit.SpikeArrest.BurstProtection.exceed.count > 0)</Condition>
                <Name>RaiseCustomFault</Name>
            </Step>
...
```

Once the condition is met, you raise your own custom fault msg.

It's also worth noting that SpikeArrest doesn't really have a count, per say.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912316/apigee-spikearrest-behavior/21914049#21914049) on another SO question on SpikeArrest.

**IMPORTANT EDIT**
`ratelimit.<spike_arrest_policy_name>.exceed.count>0` check does not work at this time.  A good alternative, as suggested by Michael, is to leave `continueOnError="true"` (the default). Let the Spike Arrest fault, and then at the top of Proxy file, leverage the FaultRules section.  You can check for the proper FaultRule condition as follows:

```
    <FaultRules>
      <FaultRule name="FaultHandling">
        <Step>
            <Condition>(fault.name = "SpikeArrestViolation")</Condition>
            <Name>RaiseSpikeCustomFault</Name>
        </Step>
      </FaultRule>
    </FaultRules>
```

The `fault.name` values are listed on the public docs site under each topic, so SpikeArrest's are [here](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/shield-apis-using-spikearrest).  See under "Policy-specific error codes."

Comment: Yes, that did it. But for some reason `ratelimit.SpikeArrest.BurstProtection.exceed.count` was always set to 0 so I had to build the condition using `(ratelimit.failed is true)`. There shouldn't be more than one SpikeArrest policy per proxy ever, so I'm assuming that a single ratelimit.failed check should be sufficient and there's no need to use the policy name there.

Comment: Thank you, Oscar.  This looks to be a bug.  I will edit my answer to include an alternative.  You also found an interesting alternative, but the concern is that if you are using other rate limiting (such as Quota policy), a Quota violation may trigger the RaiseFault you intend for Spike Arrest.

Comment: Yes, multiple rate limit checks are not possible with my simplified solution. That shouldn't be a problem for us but in any case, I migrated my solution to use your final suggestion. Thanks again.

Comment: Great, Oscar.  You may already be doing this, but please ensure you're also using DefaultFaultRules to process any faults that fall through the FaultRules.  See more at http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/fault-handling.

Answer (score 1):

I've not used the `<FaultRules>` configuration inside of policies before but I do know that the SpikeArrest policy itself will raise a fault in the message flow if the rate is violated.  This sends the message to the fault flow, `<FaultRules>`, where you can then define a policy like `RaiseFault.BurstProtection` to set a custom fault response. See more info here: http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/fault-handling

Most policies raise a fault when their execution determines that a fault should be raised (rate limits, xml/json injection policies, oauth v2 policies, etc).

I'm not sure the type of policy you're using for `RaiseFault.BurstProtection`, but when you use the approach of Apigee's `<FaultRules>` defined in the ProxyEndpoint or TargetEndpoint, you can have an AssignMessage policy to overwrite the response message, setting the custom fault response.

I like designing my proxies using the fault rules flows in Apigee to build more of a framework for fault handling vs. a per-policy configuration for fault rules.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that FaultRules in policies had been deprecated. The documentation on fault handling doesn't state that and the default policy code that is generated by the development UI still generates tags for FaultRules.

Comment: What I can't quite see yet is this: why is it better to use AssignMessage to set custom errors, instead of using RaiseFault, also with a custom error payload?

Comment: Using RaiseFault will stop message flow.  AssignMessage does not.  You would use AssignMessage when you're already in the error flow, otherwise another RaiseFault will completely stop the flow and not allow for any further error processing.