# Apigee Throttling Scenario

Tags: api, backend, apigee, throttling

Our organisation is in the process of migrating to Apigee.

What we want to achieve is the following scenario. Can you please advise me how to do it? 
Maybe using together SpikeArrest, Quota and ConcurrentRatelimit?

**I would like to ask for practical example configuration of a proxy, as guide lines how to link the policies to achieve the desired result.**

I have been through the documentation and it is somewhat skim and has gaps, as to what is distributed, what is not, etc.

```
http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/shield-apis-using-spikearrest
http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/rate-limit-api-traffic-using-quota#identifying-apps
http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/throttle-backend-connections-using-concurrentratelimit
```

An example gap is my previous question about SpikeArrest, which arouse as a result of configuring SpikeArrest and not getting the expected behaviour, due to the fact that in the documentaiton it's not specified that SpikeArrests are not distributed:
[Apigee SpikeArrest Sync Across MessageProcessors (MPs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23298849/apigee-spikearrest-sync-across-messageprocessors-mps/23299984)

These guys were also caught out by the same scenario:
[Apigee - SpikeArrest behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912316/apigee-spikearrest-behavior?lq=1)

**Scenario and Desired Result:**

In our organisation we have **6 MessageProcessors (MP)** and I assume they are working in a strictly round robin manner.

We have the following backend Api - **Api-1**.

**Api-1** has consumers from within our organisation alongside it's Apigee consumers.
We want to prevent our **Api-1** from getting hammered and going down.
Lets say it has been loadtested to take a maximum of **50 requests per second**.
We have calculated that through Apigee we want to limit at a maximum of 30 requests per second, as the other **20 requests per second** capacity is for the users from within our organisations (mainly our own other products) that do not go through Apigee.

From the number of DeveloperApps consuming **Api-1** through Apigee, we have identified, 4 Apps/Clients, which have the highest spikes in consumption.
Out of the **30ps** rate allocated to Apigee, we would like to be able to be able to allocate a **5ps** for each of these **4 high consumption** DevApps/Clients and have the rest **10ps** rate shared amongst the other DevApps/Clients.

The main problem I keep getting at the TargetEndpoint is the one described here, as SpikeArrest policy is not distributed across MessageProcessors: [Apigee SpikeArrest Sync Across MessageProcessors (MPs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23298849/apigee-spikearrest-sync-across-messageprocessors-mps/23299984)

**How can we get around it and achieve the desired scenario?**

Here are examples of what I had tried to try and make achieve the desired behaviour:

**TargetEndpoint of a proxy:**

**ConcurrentRatelimit:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ConcurrentRatelimit async="true" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="Concurrent-Rate-Limit-1">
    <DisplayName>Concurrent Rate Limit 1</DisplayName>
    <AllowConnections count="1" ttl="5"/>
    <Distributed>true</Distributed>
    <TargetIdentifier name="default"></TargetIdentifier>
</ConcurrentRatelimit>
```

**SpikeArrest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<SpikeArrest async="true" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="Spike-Arrest-2">
    <DisplayName>Spike Arrest 2</DisplayName>
    <FaultRules/>
    <Properties/>
    <Identifier ref="request.header.some-header-name"/>
    <MessageWeight ref="request.header.weight"/>
    <Rate>30ps</Rate>
</SpikeArrest>
```

Also what happens if the organisation adds or removes MPs without my knowledge, this will totally scramble the throttling?

Much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried dividing it by the number of known message processors? That is, if you have

Comment: That's my current solution. At the moment I have the spike arrest set to 5ps (30ps / 6mp = 5ps). I am looking for a better solution as if for any reason the numbers need to go really low, as far as I know, you can't put something like 0.5ps as a rate on a SpikeArrest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with synchronizing spike arrest across MP is that you're already under severe load (in theory) and creating additional chatter between MP in a high load could have impact on the very tool you're using to protect from high load.

Therefore your only option in Per Second restrictions is to do the math and divide by MP. For minutes and above you can do the Quota policy with no identifier and distributed and synchronous turned on.

Comment: I do have a Quota Policy implemented as well. Can the ConcurrentRateLimit help in anyway in the above scenario? How does it work? What does it do exactly? In the documentation it says: "The ConcurrentRatelimit policy enables you to throttle inbound connections to your backend services from API proxies running on Apigee Edge. In distributed environments, app traffic may be managed by many replicated API proxies." http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/throttle-backend-connections-using-concurrentratelimit

Comment: Also Quota Policies seem to be distributed across Message Processors and it doesn't seem to "additional chatter between MP", so I don't see why SpikeArrest Policies are not synchronised in the same way?

If for any reason the number of MPs changes without my knowledge this will mess up the throttling and bring down the API which I am trying to protect from exactly that scenario. Protection from DOS attacks and throttling are my teams' prime concerns and if that doesn't work well, it's rendering Apigee useless to us.